# KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'examples' doesn't exist)"

Tags: tensorflow, hdf5, tensorflow-federated

I got this error when I want to create a HDF5ClientData instance just like the emnsit. Here is my code:

```
TestNIST = tff.simulation.hdf5_client_data.HDF5ClientData("mynist.hdf5")
```

And I have added some data into mynist.hdf5 before. I don't know why it happen.

[the instance of emnist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5gxa.png)

here is my error like:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-00a78fdc8682> in <module>()
----> 1 TestNIST = tff.simulation.hdf5_client_data.HDF5ClientData("mynist.hdf5")

1 frames
h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    262 
    263         Named HDF5 object (Dataset, Group, Datatype)
--> 264             A hard link is created at "name" which points to the
    265             given object.
    266 

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5o.pyx in h5py.h5o.open()

KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'examples' doesn't exist)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I know why this error happens. I read the notation of hdf5_client_data.py again and I find this:
This class expects that the HDF5 file has a top-level group `examples` which
  contains further subgroups, one per user, named by the user ID.
My top-group is not named 'examples'.